# show data in my android app(saving works just fine now)

Tags: android, sql, save, insert-update

hey, 
now i can save data in my db, but it doesn't show up in the database activity itself.

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onCreateDBAndDBTabled(); //DB und Tables erstellen wenn noch nicht vorhanden
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

```
private void onCreateDBAndDBTabled() {
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE
                + " ( id integer primary key autoincrement,"+ 
                      "Name varchar(100),"+ 
                      "Comment varchar(128),"+ 
                      "BookingDetails varchar(255),"+ 
                      "CustomerProject integer(3),"+ 
                      "editable varchar(15))"
                +";");

    }


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, MENU_PROJECTS, 0, R.string.menuProjects)
        .setShortcut('1', 'f')
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
         return true;

      }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case MENU_PROJECTS:
        Intent iProjects = new Intent(this, Projects.class);
        startActivity(iProjects);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

}

This is the insert statement

{

```
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
                        cv.put ( "Name", Name.getText().toString() ); 
                        cv.put ( "Comment", Comment.getText().toString() ); 
                        cv.put ( "BookingDetails", BookingDetails.getText().toString() ); 
                        cv.put ( "Project_kind", i ); 
                        cv.put ( "Editable", Editable.getText().toString() ); 
                        myDB.insert ( Projectshome.MY_DB_TABLE , null, cv); 
                    }
                    finish();
                    return true;
this is my manifest:
```

```
</manifest>
```

here is my LogCat-output the moment i hit the save-button:

```
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719): Error inserting BookingDetails=BookingDetails Project_kind=0 Name=Name Editable=Editable Comment=Comment
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table projects has no column named Project_kind: , while compiling: INSERT INTO projects(BookingDetails, Project_kind, Name, Editable, Comment) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:925)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1300)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1173)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at versuch.datenbank.Projects_New.onOptionsItemSelected(Projects_New.java:132)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2085)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:820)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:813)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:519)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
02-09 11:41:53.850: ERROR/Database(719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

hope you can help me again :)

Comment: what is the log? , logcat output ?

Comment: well i don't have any... that's kind of my second problem at the moment...

Comment: what about uses-permissions in the manifest?

Comment: I think you should remove the semicolon given at end of query.

Comment: i posted my manifest in my edited question. if there is sth missing i would be more than appreciative if you would tell me ;)

Comment: How does your app abort? Is it a Force Close? Does it just disappear? If you post your onClick, we may be able to infer a little more. Are you sure there's no logcat output? I ask because even for an app that produces no errors at all, there'll be logcat output from Android relating to what is happening - you'll at least have GC messages, messages when your activities start...

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information. As in the error log. The error might be in the statement itself.Add the details from the logcat first.It will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think the insert query is missing word 'values'. Try printing that query string on console executing the same through console on db. That may help you identify error.

Comment: Did you try printing the query string onto console. Also check if there is traces.txt in data/data/anr folder. Sometimes the log goes to this file.

Answer (score 0):

I have two things to point out:

What is `i` in your SQL query? Is it an `int`? If so that might be the problem because the way you are using it, it should be a `String`.

Secondly, why don't you use the `insert` convenience function of SQLiteDatabase?

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put ( "Name", Name.getText().toString() );
cv.put ( "Comment", Comment.getText().toString() );
cv.put ( "BookingDetails", BookingDetails.getText().toString() );
cv.put ( "Project_kind", i );
cv.put ( "Editable", Editable.getText().toString() );
myDB.insert ( Projectshome.MY_DB_TABLE, null, cv );
```

This takes all the complexity of building the SQL query out of inserting rows - it will ensure that the query is correctly built, all you have to do is build the `ContentValues` map properly.

Comment: thanks, now it doesn't abort anymore ;) but it als doesn't show up in the list/ my db... very strange...

Comment: How are you trying to get the data out of the database? Are you using a cursor to point to the data? An adapter to link it to the listview? You'll also need to provide code to manage the creating and re-using of the views so Android can manage your resources effectively.

I'll put up another answer with some example code when I can - should be within about the next day.

Comment: Actually, just looked closer at your logcat output, your original question mentioned ProjectKind, probably as a variable and I took that as the column name. From your create code aboce, you should change Project_kind to CustomerProject

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's how I do it:

row.xml (Used for each row in the list view):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4px"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/itemDescription"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@+id/TextView01"
            android:id="@+id/Category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="@+id/TextView01"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/itemManufacturer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="@+id/TextView01"
            android:id="@+id/EAN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I extend `CursorAdapter` to create or re-use existing `ListActivity` rows (supplied by the `ListActivity`) defined in row.xml. `bindView` is used if Android wants you to re-use an existing row resource, `newView` is used if it wants you to create a new one:

```
class BarcodeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    BarcodeAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(kitchenListInventoryActivity.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                                             Cursor c) {
        BarcodeHolder holder=(BarcodeHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                                             ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row = null;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        BarcodeHolder holder=new BarcodeHolder(row);

        row.setTag(holder);

        return(row);
    }
}
```

`BarcodeHolder` is just a convenience class to hold a Java representation of the row, which I associate with the `ListActivity` item with `setTag` above. Not necessarily the most elegant way, but it simplifies things.:

```
    static class BarcodeHolder {
        private TextView description=null;
        private TextView manufacturer=null;
        private TextView EAN = null;
        private TextView category = null;
        private View row=null;

        BarcodeHolder(View row) {
            this.row=row;

            description=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
            manufacturer=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemManufacturer);
            EAN=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.EAN);
            category = ( TextView )row.findViewById(R.id.Category);
        }

        void populateFrom(Cursor c, BarcodeHelper helper) {
            Cursor invCursor = helper.getByInventoryEAN(helper.getBarcode(c));
            Cursor dbCursor = helper.getByEAN(helper.getBarcode(c));
            dbCursor.moveToFirst();
            invCursor.moveToFirst();
            int qty = helper.getQuantity ( invCursor );
            String desc = helper.getDescription(dbCursor) + " (" + String.valueOf( qty ) + ")" ;
            description.setText( desc );
            manufacturer.setText(helper.getManufacturer(dbCursor));
            category.setText(helper.getCategory(dbCursor));
        }
    }
```

To bring this all together, I call `initList` in my `onCreate` of the `ListActivity`:

```
private void initList ( ) {
    if ( model != null ) {
        stopManagingCursor(model);
        model.close();
    }

    model = helper.getAllInventory();
    startManagingCursor(model);
    adapter = new BarcodeAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

`model` is a `Cursor`, and `adapter` is an instance of `BarcodeAdapter`, which I've shown above. I tell the `ListActivity` to use this adapter so that I can correctly populate the rows. `getAllInventory` is a member of `BarcodeHelper` which overrides `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
public Cursor getAllInventory( ) {
    String sql = "SELECT _id, EAN, quantity FROM Inventory ORDER BY EAN";
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null));
}
```

The helper object just contains a collection of convenience functions.

All of this is based on [CommonsWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) excellent Android tutorial book which I cannot recommend enough, but there should be enough here to get you going.