# Can't load my SQLite data into my ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to load the contents of my SQLite table into a ListView using the following code.

```
myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);  
Cursor cursor = getData();  
CursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item, cursor, fields, null);  
menuList.setAdapter(datasource);  //My ListView  

private Cursor getData() {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null,null, ORDER_BY);  
    return cursor;  
}
```

When I run the app it passes through this code and then throws an error. Am I using the correct technique for adding data to a ListView?

Comment: what's the error/stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a little more information.

- Where does it crash?
- What is the error that it gives?

You are using `adapt` but you do not declare it or set it to anything in your code snippet - if it's `null`, then that will be a problem.

```
menuList.setAdapter(adapt);  //My ListView
```

Take a look at my example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897800/show-data-in-my-android-appsaving-works-just-fine-now/4963989#4963989) for how I use `ListView`s with `SQLite`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry about the typo, I've changed it now, it was because I was using to separate pieces of code. Anyway, thanks for the link, it's pointed me in the right direction, if I use your technique I think that will resolve my problem